# Permutation of labels in conditional probabilities

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider the random variables $X,Y$ defined on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Suppose $Y$ is a discrete random variable with support $\mathcal{Y}\subset \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $X$ is a random variable (it could be **continuous or discrete**) with support $\mathcal{X}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$

Suppose also that we have a sample of $N$ observations for $Y,X$ denoted by $\{Y_i, X_i\}_{i=1}^N$ i.i.d. over $i$ with $N$ large. Let $\boldsymbol{Y}:=(Y_1,...,Y_n)\in \mathcal{Y}^n$ and $\boldsymbol{X}:=(X_1,...,X_n)\in \mathcal{X}^n$.

Let $\mathcal{N}:=\{1,2,...,N\}$ and consider $\varphi:\mathcal{N}\rightarrow \mathcal{N}$ being a bijective function representing a permutation of labels. For any $\boldsymbol{y}\in \mathcal{Y}^n$, let $\boldsymbol{y}^\varphi$ be the realisation of $\boldsymbol{Y}$ obtained by applying $\varphi$ to $\boldsymbol{y}$. For any $\boldsymbol{x}\in \mathcal{X}^n$, let $\boldsymbol{x}^\varphi$ be the realisation of $\boldsymbol{X}$ obtained by applying $\varphi$ to $\boldsymbol{x}$.

E.g., if $N=3$, $\boldsymbol{y}:=(1,2,3)$, $\varphi(1)=2$, $\varphi(2)=3$, $\varphi(3)=1$, then $\boldsymbol{y}^\varphi:=(3,1,2)$.

Consider
$$
P(\boldsymbol{Y}=\boldsymbol{y}|\boldsymbol{X}=\boldsymbol{x})
$$

When $X$ is discrete it can be shown that 
$$
P(\boldsymbol{Y}=\boldsymbol{y}|\boldsymbol{X}=\boldsymbol{x})=P(\boldsymbol{Y}=\boldsymbol{y}^\varphi|\boldsymbol{X}=\boldsymbol{x}^\varphi)
$$
simply by the fact that $\{Y_i,X_i\}_{i=1}^N$ are i.i.d. across $i$.

***Question: Does this hold (or make sense) also when $X$ is continuous?***

Comment: The key fact here is that, for each fixed $(x,y)$, $$P(Y=y\mid X=x)$$ depends only on the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$. Now, fix some permutation $\varphi$ and consider $\psi=\varphi^{-1}$, then $$P(Y=y^\varphi\mid X=x^\varphi)=P(Y^\psi=y\mid X^\psi=x)$$ hence the identity you are interested in follows from the fact that $(X^\psi,Y^\psi)$ and $(X,Y)$ follow the same distribution. And this, in turn, holds true because, by independence, each of these is the product of $N$ times the distribution of $(X_1,Y_1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it makes sense.

Can you see that we have the following? $$\def\P{\mathop{\mathsf P}} \P(Y_1{=}a_1, Y_2{=}a_2\mid X_1{=}b_1, X_2{=}b_2) ~=~ \P(Y_1{=}a_2, Y_2{=}a_1\mid X_1{=}b_2, X_2{=}b_1)$$

Just extend the same to a multitude of $\{(X_i,Y_i)\}$ pairs.

---

For the discrete random variable case, it is obvious.

$$\begin{align} &~\P(Y_1{=}a_1, Y_2{=}a_2\mid X_1{=}b_1, X_2{=}b_2)
\\[2ex] ~=&~ \dfrac{\P(Y_1{=}a_1, X_1{=}b_1, Y_2{=}a_2, X_2{=}b_2)}{\P(X_1{=}b_1,X_2{=}b_2)} &&\text{conditional probability}
\\[2ex] =&~\dfrac{\P(Y_1{=}a_1, X_1{=}b_1)\P( Y_2{=}a_2, X_2{=}b_2)}{\P(X_1{=}b_1)\P(X_2{=}b_2)} && \text{independence across indices}
\\[2ex] =&~\dfrac{\P(Y_1{=}a_2, X_1{=}b_2)\P( Y_2{=}a_1, X_2{=}b_1)}{\P(X_1{=}b_2)\P(X_2{=}b_1)} && \text{identical distribution across indices}
\\[2ex] =&~ \mathsf P(Y_1{=}a_2, Y_2{=}a_1\mid X_1{=}b_2, X_2{=}b_1) &&\text{and back again}\end{align}$$

The continuous case is much the same, though using probability density functions rather than probability masses.

$$\def\d{\mathop{\rm d}}\begin{align} &~\P(Y_1{=}a_1, Y_2{=}a_2\mid X_1{=}b_1, X_2{=}b_2)
\\[2ex] ~=&~ \left.\dfrac{\frac{\d~~}{\d s}\frac{\d~~}{\d t}\P(Y_1{=}a_1, X_1{\leqslant}s, Y_2{=}a_2, X_2{\leqslant}t)}{\frac{\d ~~}{\d s}\frac{\d~~}{\d t}\P(X_1{\leqslant}s,X_2{\leqslant}t)}\right\vert_{s=b_1,t=b_2}
\\[2ex] \vdots&\\[2ex] =&~ \mathsf P(Y_1{=}a_2, Y_2{=}a_1\mid X_1{=}b_2, X_2{=}b_1) \end{align}$$

Comment: The derivative approach allows to avoid using the true definition of conditional probabilities, but it prevents to solve the general case since the derivatives of the joint CDFs involved do not always exist. To sum up, every distribution is not either discrete or absolutely continuous (and even if they are absolutely continuous, the derivative argument is more tricky than this post may lead to believe)

Comment: @Did: despite the proof, do you agree on the initial answer?

Comment: @STF See comment to main.